# How can I upload and display file to html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to upload files to my `html` and display it, need something like an attachment, I choose my file (image,text,pdf,excel...) and display it.

I have already tried this code but it only show the text name I need something like it but also display content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "file");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to see the file content before upload or after upload ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear, but for uploading a file you need a server-side language
and If you want to show your uploaded file you have to send the file via AJAX to a server-side language (like PHP, Node.js, Python and etc.)

something like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function uploadFile(){
    let file = document.getElementById("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
   //show upload progress
}
function completeHandler(event){
   let tmp = document.getElementById('showImg');
   tmp.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+tmp+"')"
}
function errorHandler(event){
    //error handler
}
function abortHandler(event){
    //abort handler
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <div id="showImg"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php :

```php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "test_uploads/$fileName";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
```

P.s : Styling isn't really great in this example you can append an `img` tag or something else, It's just an example for you to understand the concept

Hope this helps you

Comment: appreciate your help,but i'm not trying to upload to a server i just want to display in html page

Comment: this was my question. if its local, why even use a browser? if its a server, you'll need a backend. You should create an S3 bucket and upload files there, them run the static website from that folder. might get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have a resume on my personal site for example, its a PDF document.

I just linked to it with an anchor tag

```
<html>
<a href="docs/Resume.pdf" target="new">Resume</a>

</html>
```

Hope this helps. let me know if you have other questions and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: thank you anyway but it's not what i'm searching for ..i'm trying to display local files to my html page..i press attachment button, search for file in my local pc ,upload it to html and display it...

Comment: are you just looking for a page that opens your files in the browser or are you looking to store them on a server somewhere?

Comment: bottom `html` tag should be closed ; )

Comment: yes i'm only looking to display may file ,no need for server... recently i found iframe tag i think it will help me but i'm still discovering it ,, appreciate your support guys

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>

      <body>
        <input name="file" type="file" id="file"/>
        <img id="preview" />
        <script>
                  $(function()
{
   $("#file").on('change', function(){
   // Display image on the page for viewing
        readURL(this,"preview");

   });
});

function readURL(input , tar) {  
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) { // got sth

    // Clear image container
    $("#" + tar ).removeAttr('src'); 

    $.each(input.files , function(index,ff)  // loop each image 
    {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Put image in created image tags
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#' + tar).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(ff);

    });
    }
}
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you,your code only display file name , i need also display its content

Comment: thank you, this code solve the text file display,but it can't display image pdf ...